# LSTM classifier yields low accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I am new to deep learning and I'm trying to use LSTM for a binary classification problem  - price up/down movements of a stock using an input set of 11 time series, where most are discrete (take values between -2,2). I have ca 2500 rows of training data. I prepare the data using keras TimeseriesGenerator class:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

y_train[0:5] = array([1., 0., 1., 1., 0.])
x_train[0:5]=array([[-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,
        -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,
         1.73995571e-03,  1.14900000e+01],
       [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,
        -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  2.00000000e+00,
         7.42144323e-03,  1.22800000e+01],
       [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,
        -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -2.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -2.00000000e+00,
        -3.35423197e-02,  1.19600000e+01],
       [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,
        -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00,  2.00000000e+00,  2.00000000e+00,
        -1.94615634e-02,  1.17500000e+01],
       [-1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00,
        -1.00000000e+00, -1.00000000e+00, -2.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+00, -2.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,
         1.86900430e-02,  1.14300000e+01]])

def prep_data_dl(cols, batch_size, look_back):
    X_train, X_val, X_test=make_x(cols) #create X from feature set based on columns of choice
    scaler.fit(X_train)
    scaled_train=scaler.transform(X_train)
    scaler.fit(X_val)
    scaled_val1=scaler.transform(X_val)
    scaler.fit(X_test)
    scaled_test=scaler.transform(X_test)
    scaled_train.shape, scaled_val.shape, y_train.shape, y_val.shape
    n_feature=scaled_train.shape[1]
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, y_train,length=n_steps, batch_size=batch_size)
    val_generator=tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_val, y_val, length=n_steps, batch_size=batch_size)
    test_generator=tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_test, y_test, length=n_steps, batch_size=batch_size)
    return n_feature, train_generator, val_generator, test_generator

batch_size=16
n_steps=15
learn_rate=0.00005
dropout=0.1
neurons=25
n_features, train_generator, val_generator, test_generator=prep_data_dl(cols_x, batch_size, n_steps)

def build_model(neurons, n_features, l_rate,dropout):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))   
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=l_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model=build_model(neurons,n_features, learn_rate, dropout)

Model summary:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 25)                3800      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 25)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 26        
=================================================================
Total params: 3,826
Trainable params: 3,826
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________

monitor = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30, min_delta=1e-3, verbose=2, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)

history= model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, epochs=200,verbose=2,batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,callbacks=[monitor])
```

The problem is that classification accuracy is very low, ca 50%, which is approximately what the percentage of positives in the output variable is.

I've tried adding extra neurons, LSTM layers, extra dense layers, tweaking the learning rate, batch size, look back period without success. Before perhaps moving on to other models, I have to ask: is there something wrong in the code? Do I need to one hot encode y? Do I need to do extra pre-processing?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: It might also be that there is nothing in your data to tell you whether a specific stock is going to go up and down. The underlying assumptions of any Machine Learning endeavor that there IS a pattern to be found, but it's just an assumptions.

Comment: I've read publication with examples on predicting stock market directions with simpler model (not deep learning) and the results where also in the same range (50%). Conclusion was not that the model is bad, but that the inherent process exhibit a lot of randomness that was not predictable given only past stock price.

Comment: If you did get better result with a regular classifier in this case it might means that you don't have enough data to feed your model.  This models are indeed powerful but 2500 instances is a small training set. I had the same kind of behavior on NLP model where regular classifier where outperforming complex Neural Net due to limited data.